# Scatter plot Text labels in R

Tags: r, plot

[image: I am plotting categorical variable vs continuous variable, AGE vs Smoking habits]
Below is the code.

```
stripchart(Age~Smoke, data = survey_clean_data , pch=16 , col = "blue", method = "jitter" ,main = "AGE VS SMOKE",na.rm = T)
```

I want to add labels to it like below image, 
[image]

I tried several options.. but it is getting written on top of of other.

```
means = c(paste("mean_Age =",roumean(survey_clean_data[Smoke == "Heavy","Age"],na.rm =T)),
          paste("mean_Age =",mean(survey_clean_data[Smoke == "Never","Age"],na.rm =T)),
          paste("mean_Age =",mean(survey_clean_data[Smoke == "Regul","Age"],na.rm =T)),
          paste("mean_Age =",mean(survey_clean_data[Smoke == "Occas","Age"],na.rm =T)))


text(50,survey_clean_data$Smoke,labels =  means)
```

DATA: library(MASS) attach(survey)

Comment: For the R tag we ask that you provide a reproducible example (i.e. the data and the code). If you provide the data then I can show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. The main thing is that you are sending `text()` four labels (the contents of `means`), but a number of y-coordinates equal to the number of data points, since you are sending it `survey_clean_data`. R tries to equalize these uneven vectors, resulting in the over plotting.

Instead, you might do (data are artificial since you didn't provide any):

```
stripchart(Age~Smoke, data = survey_clean_data , pch=16 , col = "blue", method = "jitter" ,main = "AGE VS SMOKE",na.rm = T)

means <- aggregate(Age~Smoke, data = survey_clean_data, FUN = mean) # mean of each category
means$y <- 1:4 # add y-coordinates for each category

with(means, text(50, Smoke, labels = sprintf('Mean Age = %0.1f', Age))) # plot text labels on top of stripchart
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

answer give by jdobres worked fine. The below is one more solution.

add `ylim=c(0.8,4.2)` parameter to the scatterplot. You can adjust these ranges from c(1,4) to c(0.8,4.2). The later one worked for me.

```
stripchart(Age~Smoke, data = survey_clean_data , pch=16 , col = 634, method = "jitter" ,main = "AGE VS SMOKE",na.rm = T,ylim=c(0.8,4.2))
```

With the below line you can adjust the vertical height of the text.
eg: +0.1, -0.1 etc

```
text(50,c(1:4)+0.1,means)
```